# I have an error with ssl guzzle in symfony

Tags: symfony, guzzle

I use guzzle on Symfony

```
$this->client = new Client(['verify' => '/etc/ssl/certs/_.xxxxx.im.crt']);

$this->client->request(...........)
```

cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)"

- without ssl it works
- I checked that the file .crt exists

HELP !

Comment: Are you sure that Guzzle can access the certificate file (permissions)? Try placing the certificate file within projects directory where the permissions might be looser.

Comment: to test, I put the cacert.pem in the  /src folder